# Помогите разобраться с RESTful http кэшированием

Tags: http, rest, кэширование, клиент-сервер

Я разрабатываю мобильное приложение которое подгружает данные с нашего REST-сервера. Например это список товаров. На сервере товары хранятся в базе данных и их таблица имеет следующую структуру:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 23.08.2015 06:00:00 | хлеб  | 10    |
| 2  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | масло | 55    |
| 3  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | сыр   | 180   |
| 4  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | сахар | 80    |
```

Моя цель разобраться со стандартной схемой кэширования динамических данных. Сейчас мое кэширование работает таким образом:

1)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: 24.08.2015 18:00:00
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { "id" : "1", "name" : "хлеб", "price" : 10 },
  { "id" : "2", "name" : "масло", "price" : 55 },
  { "id" : "3", "name" : "сыр", "price" : 180 },
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "сахар", "price" : 80 }
]
```

После того как сервер отдал мне ответ я кэширую данные в аналогичной таблице в локальной базе данных с единственным отличием, я выставляю updated_at каждого из элементов == Last-Modified пришедшему с сервера. Таким образом моя локальная БД выглядит следующим образом:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | хлеб  | 10    |
| 2  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | масло | 55    |
| 3  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | сыр   | 180   |
| 4  | 24.08.2015 18:00:00 | сахар | 80    |
```

Затем я посылаю следующий запрос:

2)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Modified-Since: 24.08.2015 18:00:00


HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

[Пустое тело]
```

В запросе в заголовке If-Modified-Since я подставляю самую последнюю дату из поля updated_at, т.к. на сервере данные не обновились и не добавились то мне возвращается ответ 304. Допустим на сервере добавили одну запись и еще одну существующую изменили:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 23.08.2015 06:00:00 | хлеб  | 10    |
| 2  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | масло | 55    |
| 3  | 24.08.2015 12:00:00 | сыр   | 180   |
| 4  | 26.08.2015 09:00:00 | сахар | 90    |
| 5  | 26.08.2015 08:00:00 | мука  | 60    |
```

Снова посылаем запрос

3)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Modified-Since: 24.08.2015 18:00:00


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: 26.08.2015 09:00:00
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "сахар", "price" : 90 },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "мука", "price" : 60 }
]
```

Получив этот ответ я изменяю запись с id == 4 в соответствии с ответом, и добавляю новую запись. У обеих этих записей я ставлю updated_at == Last-Modified из соответствующего ответа сервера. Моя реализация кэширования меня полностью устраивала до тех пор пока я не ввел отборы по параметрам GET запроса. Допустим я ОЧИСТИЛ ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ КЭШ и отправляю следующий запрос:

4)

```
GET /api/v1/products?min_price=60&max_price=100 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: 26.08.2015 09:00:00
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "сахар", "price" : 90 },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "мука", "price" : 60 }
]
```

Здесь в параметрах GET строки я передаю min_price=60 и max_price=100. Сервер согласно моему запросу отбирает среди существующих элементов, и отдает мне 2 подходящих, согласно схемы кэширования он подставляет максимальную величину updated_at среди выбранных элементов в Last-Modified. Мое клиентское приложение кэширует пришедшие данные. Локальная база выглядит следующим образом:

```
| id | updatet_at          | name  | price |
|----|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 4  | 26.08.2015 09:00:00 | сахар | 90    |
| 5  | 26.08.2015 09:00:00 | мука  | 60    |
```

Теперь когда я отправлю запрос на получение всех продуктов:

5)

```
GET /api/v1/products HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Modified-Since: 26.08.2015 09:00:00


HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

[Пустое тело]
```

Получается такая ситуация что я не могу получить более старые(с меньшим updated_at) продукты из-за того что я уже получил продукты с самым болшим updated_at, таким образом моя схема кэширования сломалась. Подскажите как правильно использовать стандартное HTTP кэширование для динамических данных?

Answer (score 1):

Запоминайте время последнего запроса по каждому типу запросов. Теперь, когда следующий раз будете слать `GET /api/v1/products` отправляйте не максимальную дату с базы, а время, когда Вы последний раз слать этот запрос. Для хранения хорошо подойтет любой хеш или просто таблица в базе с полями "url" и "last request".

С другой стороны, модифицировать время последней модификации в записей в базе, когда делает запрос вида `GET /api/v1/products?min_price=60&max_price=100` как то неестественно. Но при вышеприведенной схеме оно все равно будет работать правильно.

Comment: Вы говорите о том что запрос `GET /api/v1/products` и запрос `GET /api/v1/products?min_price=60&max_price=100` разные, и для них нужно хранить разный Last-Modified? Но ведь тогда если в нашей системе добавится отбор по цвету, размеру, качеству, оценке.. то мне придется сохранять для каждого из них эту дату, более того мне придется сохранять эту дату для каждого сочетания этих параметров. Это очень усложнит схему и сделает ее не масштабируемой.

Comment: да, с точки зрения restfull архитектуры это разные запросы.
Да, дату придется сохранять для каждого типа запросов. Но я не вижу ничего сложного. Несколько строк кода.